# CAS authentication failing with Drupal but working as standalone

Tags: drupal, cas

I am trying to setup CAS server locally and I have Drupal running locally as well. I am using Mongo DB for CAS [ticket registry](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/MongoDb-Ticket-Registry.html#mongodb-ticket-registry) and [user authentication](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#mongodb-authentication). For CAS service registry I am using file-based [JSON service registry](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/JSON-Service-Management.html#json-service-registry).

My Service registry:

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "id": 3,
  "serviceId": "http(s)?:\\/\\/relo.local(:\\d{4,5})?(\\/.*)?$",
  "name": "relo.local",
  "evaluationOrder": 10,
  "accessStrategy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
    "enabled": true,
    "ssoEnabled": true
  },
  "attributeReleasePolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy"
  }
}
```

In MongoDB I created a collection called `accounts` in which I have created some dummy user records like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c24f234e51c56a02af5873f"),
    "username" : "casuser",
    "password" : "casuser",
    "firstname" : "wohn",
    "lastname" : "smith",
    "mail" : "casuser@test.com"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c24f24de51c56a02af58757"),
    "username" : "wasuser",
    "password" : "wasuser",
    "firstname" : "wohn",
    "lastname" : "smith",
    "mail" : "wasuser@test.com"
}
```

For the ticket registry, I do not need to create any collection. CAS is taking care of creating ticket registry collection and insert a record in that when I try to log in.

Drupal is using [cas](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas) module which uses [phpCAS](https://github.com/apereo/phpCAS) library to connect with CAS server.

- Drupal version: 7.34
- phpCAS version: 1.3.0
- CAS Version: 6.1.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT

CAS provide its own login screen. After all these configurations I am able to login into CAS server with `casuser` and `wasuser` accounts.

My **cas.properties** file:

```sh
# Required CAS settings
cas.server.name=https://localhost:8443
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas

# Log4j config file location
logging.config: file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
# Control log levels via properties
logging.level.org.apereo.cas=DEBUG

# Restrict admin endpoints (like /status) to localhost
# cas.adminPagesSecurity.ip=127\.0\.0\.1

# Authenticate if any handler succeeds
cas.authn.policy.any.tryAll=false

# Disable authentication with a static list of credentials
# If below line is commented then you can use default
# username/password:casuser/Mellon
cas.authn.accept.users=ram::ram,shyam::shyam

# Ticket Grant Cookie (TGC) encryption key
cas.tgc.crypto.encryption.key=<my key>
# Ticket Grant Cookie (TGC) Signing key
cas.tgc.crypto.signing.key=<my key>

# Webflow encryption key
cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key=<my key>
# Webflow signing key
cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key=<my key>

# Embedded Tomcat settings
server.servlet.context-path=/cas
server.port=8443
server.ssl.keyStore=file:/etc/cas/thekeystore
server.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
server.ssl.keyPassword=changeit

# JSON Service Registry
cas.serviceRegistry.json.location=file:/etc/cas/config/services-staging

# MongoDb Ticket registry
cas.ticket.registry.mongo.host=localhost
cas.ticket.registry.mongo.port=27017
cas.ticket.registry.mongo.userId=casDbAdmin
cas.ticket.registry.mongo.password=admin
cas.ticket.registry.mongo.databaseName=casdb
cas.ticket.registry.mongo.authenticationDatabaseName=casdb


# MongoDb Authentication
cas.authn.mongo.host=localhost
cas.authn.mongo.port=27017
cas.authn.mongo.userId=casDbAdmin
cas.authn.mongo.password=admin
cas.authn.mongo.databaseName=casdb
cas.authn.mongo.authenticationDatabaseName=casdb
cas.authn.mongo.usernameAttribute=username
cas.authn.mongo.attributes=
cas.authn.mongo.passwordAttribute=password
cas.authn.mongo.collection=accounts

# Authentication Policy
cas.authn.policy.requiredHandlerAuthenticationPolicyEnabled=true

# Default attributes.
cas.authn.attributeRepository.defaultAttributesToRelease=firstname,lastname,mail

# Spring Webflow
cas.webflow.autoconfigure=true
cas.webflow.alwaysPauseRedirect=false
cas.webflow.refresh=true
cas.webflow.redirectSameState=false

cas.webflow.session.lockTimeout=30
cas.webflow.session.compress=false
cas.webflow.session.maxConversations=5
cas.webflow.session.storage=true
```

I have configured Drupal to use local CAS server for authentication. When I try to access Drupal it redirects me to CAS login screen. After putting credentials in the login form and submit It is failing and showing me below error which I am not able to figure out. I am not very good in JAVA. CAS has embedded Spring webflow. I think the error is related to webflow. During authentication process, CAS has something called principle resolution and attribute resolution which decides which authentication handler to used and how many attributes to attach with the response.

**Error:**

```sh
2019-01-24 14:35:32,348 INFO [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: casuser
WHAT: TGT-5-*****b6YD2V8OBQ4X-jet
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Jan 24 14:35:32 IST 2019
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================

>
2019-01-24 14:35:32,353 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/cas].[dispatcherServlet]] - <Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.apereo.cas.web.flow.GenerateServiceTicketAction@147375b3 in state 'generateServiceTicket' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause>
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

**Full Error Stack Trace:** https://pastebin.com/vEvcvFte

Any help is appreciated. I am struggling with this error for days and I am not able to figure out the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider force-updating your SNAPSHOT. While your logs don't show the commit id, it's possible you are running an old version with a bug that has since been fixed. If you examine the readme file of the project, you will find instructions on how to update the snapshot version via Gradle.

Comment: one of my colleague has CAS 5.2 version with the same configuration and he is also facing the same issue. I'll try updating my CAS.